How do I get my disk space back after uninstalling Ubuntu-24.04 from WSL2?
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 on WSL2 on Windows 10 and I noticed that even after uninstalling the distro, I didn't get back my disk space. There was 15 GB free before installation and it's been 9.5 GB free ever since I installed the distro and uninstalling it.
Disk space is sparse and I want to move it from C drive to my D drive, how do I do it? Is it good if I use Apps and Features, then search for Ubuntu 24.04 and just use the move option from there?
If no, how can I do it?
PS: The distro is supposed to be uninstalled but can I check if it still is there?
wsl -l -v

The command tells me there isn't any installed yet.

Have you tried to reboot? Did you uninstall the distribution from the Windows Store?

@Ramhound Yes, I tried rebooting too. And yes, I uninstalled from the windows store too.

In powershell, run Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss" -Recurse ... you should see where the disk image is being stored

as for moving the disk image this would seem to answer that
